# CheckedTextView with description area

Tags: android, widget, checkedtextview

I would like to know if the default android checkedtextview control comes with the option of adding secondary text below the main text, sort of a description. I've seen it in the OS's setting menus. Not sure if this is custom made or already supported by the same widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the [documentation for CheckBox?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)
I don't believe that there is a subtitle option built in. You will just have to put to Views into a layout to complete this.

Comment: I couldn't find anything documented to be honest, but the I saw several applications using the exact same form of it, so I thought that it may actually be available.

Comment: lol. Exactly, that's because it's not in the documentation because it's not supported. It would be cool to have some resource like Android for iPhone Developers and vise versa.

Comment: But I do feel your pain trying to find stuff in the docs. I often find myself looking at all the methods and not knowing the difference between several functions calls that looks the same.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I will create a compound control.

Comment: I was actually creating a settings menu. Turns out I can use android preferences to accomplish what I want, which also displays the two-lined checkbox that I was looking for.